# Lets Encrypt auto renew failing

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I am attempting to run  `~/certbot-auto renew`

but I am getting the following error

```
Attempting to renew cert from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/<domain.com>.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. www.domain.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: DNS problem: query timed out looking up CAA for www.domain.com. Skipping.
```

I have `www` and root setup for this domain both with A records pointing directly to the servers IP address.

Is this an issue with certbot or with my config? Other domains on my server have updated fine in the past.

Thanks

Comment: DNS problem: query timed would imply my DNS is incorrect but I can ping and browse to the domain fine so a DNS query is working fine else where. Is this possibly an issue with Lets Encrypts DNS servers?

Comment: I tried removing all records from `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/` & /etc/letsencrypt/archive/`, removing my sites enabled config so technically there is no nginx config for my domain on my server (to prevent redirects) and tried to create a new cert but still getting the same error `DNS problem: query timed`. Surely this is an issue with lets encrypts?

Comment: I am having this problem as well, on multiple domains. They all worked for 1+ years, and they started failing in the past couple of months. The interesting thing is that it fails from cron, but if I do a "crontab -l", then cut and paste the command to the shell, it succeeds. I'm running the renewal at 2am on the 1st and 15th of the month.